# Why do colours defined using CMYK give inconsistent results in TikZ mindmaps?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, mindmaps

## Background

I was trying to draw a mindmap using the `tikz` `mindmap` library for possible use in a `beamer` presentation.

## The Problem

Depending on my choice of colours, the colour of nodes does not match the colours of the connectors linking them to other nodes. This is true whether the connections are automatically created using the mindmap's hierarchy or whether the connections are added manually afterwards in a `\path` operation.

## MWE

This code demonstrates the problem. The first map is straight from page 662 of the manual and works fine. The second map is just like the first except that the colours used are different.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

  \tikz[mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
    \node [concept] {Root concept}
    child[concept color=red,grow=30] {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child[concept color=orange,grow=0] {node[concept] {Child concept}};

  \tikz[mindmap,concept color=magenta]
    \node [concept] {Root concept}
    child[concept color=cyan,grow=30] {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child[concept color=yellow,grow=0] {node[concept] {Child concept}};

\end{document}
```

[image: Mindmap colouring oddities]

There are two problems:

1. The node colours are not as expected. This is less obvious in the case of yellow but very obvious in the case of cyan and magenta.
2. The colours are not *consistent*. That is, the connectors seem to use colours like those I would expect, even though the nodes do not. So the connectors do not flow smoothly to/from the nodes.

## Investigation

The colours which work consistently are all defined using the RGB model. The colours which produce inconsistent results are all defined using the CMYK model. A work around is to define alternative colours in the RGB model. For example, to define a new colour, `rgbmagenta` just like `magenta` but in terms of `rgb` rather than `cmyk`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\definecolor{rgbmagenta}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{rgbcyan}{rgb}{0,1,1}
\definecolor{rgbyellow}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\begin{document}

  \tikz[mindmap,concept color=rgbmagenta]
    \node [concept] {Root concept}
    child[concept color=rgbcyan,grow=30] {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child[concept color=rgbyellow,grow=0] {node[concept] {Child concept}};

\end{document}
```

[image: Mindmap with alternative colour definitions]

## Question

Why exactly does this happen? Can it be avoided without redefining colours as I did in the workaround?

I fear this question is surely a duplicate but searching has so far turned up nothing especially enlightening. I have found threads suggesting that TikZ may be converting colours from the CMYK model to RGB but while that might explain the colours not being quite as expected, it doesn't explain the inconsistencies.

Comment: You may try `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}` or `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` in your preamble...

Comment: Thanks. I did try something along those lines but not quite that. Loading `xcolor` before `tikz` with the option `rgb` does solve the issue. Unfortunately, it does not work in a `beamer` presentation due to an option clash for `xcolor`. This is actually one reason for the 'Background' section of my question. I suspected some solutions wouldn't work in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

Since version 3.1.3, `tikz` supports CMYK shadings, so the MWE below will work without loading `pgf-cmykshadings`.

---

There is a new package, `pgf-cmykshadings` that support CMYK shadings in `pgf` and `tikz`. It is possible to produce RGB and CMYK shadings in the same document by setting the `xcolor` colour model. Just load `pgf-cmykshadings` *before* `tikz`.

In the following MWE, the first mindmap is in RGB and the second in CMYK. Both have consistent colours!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

  \selectcolormodel{rgb}
  \tikz[mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
    \node [concept] {Root concept}
    child[concept color=red,grow=30] {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child[concept color=orange,grow=0] {node[concept] {Child concept}};

  \selectcolormodel{cmyk}
  \tikz[mindmap,concept color=magenta]
    \node [concept] {Root concept}
    child[concept color=cyan,grow=30] {node[concept] {Child concept}}
    child[concept color=yellow,grow=0] {node[concept] {Child concept}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. My TikZ (3.1.10) does NOT handle CMYK shadings correctly (and passing `rgb` to `xcolor`) causes colors to be converted incorrectly, but loading this package, even while it warns about being deprecated, works and fixes things.

Answer (score 7):

TikZ (before version 3.1.3) uses RGB colors for color gradients.

With the package `xcolor` (required by `tikz` and `beamer`), you can:

1. convert a CMYK color to a RGB color:

   ```
   \colorlet{yellow}[rgb]{yellow}
   ```
2. convert a RGB color to a CMYK color:

   ```
   \colorlet{red}[cmyk]{red}
   ```

To always use RGB colors, pass the `rgb` option to `xcolor`:

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

As `beamer` requires `xcolor`, you must pass this option before:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Comment: Thanks - the `\PassOptionsToPackage` might be useful here. Why are the colours *inconsistent*, though? I could understand if, say, `magenta` produced something which was not quite magenta because it was trying to interpret a CMYK specification as an RGB one. What I don't understand is why `magenta` produces one colour for the nodes and one for the connectors.

Comment: I fear that choosing a color model different than `rgb` does not really help with shadings. In fact, it will cause (lossy) colorspace conversions, and the resulting shading will be in RGB. pgf currently supports only RGB for shadings.

Comment: The real problem remains, however: when CMYK is required, how can TikZ be made to use CMYK in gradients?